# How to toggle keyboard on iOS 8 simulator using calabash-ios

Tags: ios, calabash, calabash-ios

When a text field is touched using the touch() function the keyboard on the iOS 8 simulator does not pop up anymore. Is there a way to toggle the keyboard using the Calabash API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update to run-loop 1.0.9, calabash will do this automatically.

- https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#109
- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B2-Updating-your-run-loop-version

If, after updating to run-loop 1.0.9, you are still experiencing keyboard problems, please file a bug here:

- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues

Answer (score 4):

Please try and press "Command" + "K" . in iOS8 Simulator will not show software keyboard if it detects hardware keypad .